# Result goes blank when reading from textfile and then to insert in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, text

Here, I want to fetch record from textfile and then insert into mysql database.
I am getting result as blank.
So, am I going right or wrong with my code?

```
$local_csvfile_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test_demo/magento_prd';
$filename = $local_csvfile_path . "/orderitems100081669.txt";

if ($dh = opendir($local_csvfile_path)) {

    $cnt = 0;
    while (($lfile = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

        if ($lfile != "." && $lfile != ".." && $lfile != basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])) {
            $file = fopen($filename, "r");


            if ($file) {

                $size = filesize($filename);

                if ($size) {

                    $csvcontent = fread($file, $size);

                    fclose($file);
                    $output = explode("\n", $csvcontent);

                    foreach($output as $line) 
                    {
                        $var = explode('\t', $line, 2);
                        $arr[$var[0]] = $var[1];
                    }

                    print_r($arr);

                    $sql = mysql_query('INSERT INTO tbl_order_details(orderdet_id) VALUES ("'.$arr.'")');

                }
            } else {
                fclose($file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my text file code:

```
order_id    orderdet_productsku orderdet_iscase orderdet_qty    item_sold_price
100081669   BS8FTX1                    N               1                 2.99
```

Comment: You are concatenating an array into a string... This cannot work.

Comment: @Salketer :  Ok..!! Then how could be fetch that record and insert into mysql?

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that you are saving every line in an array but you are not saving each array element in the database. You could run a query for each line in your foreach, or keep it like that but concatenate the array elements to form a complete INSERT with many values like I did.

```
foreach($output as $line) 
{
    $var = explode('\t', $line, 2);
    $arr[$var[0]] = $var[1];
}

print_r($arr);

$sql = mysql_query('INSERT INTO tbl_order_details(orderdet_id) VALUES ("'.implode('),(',$arr).'")');
```

Basically, implode will add `),(` between each element. So to form `VALUES(5),(6)` if the values stored were 5 and 6.

You might want to play with it again as I see you are storing column one as key and column two as value, but do not state what you'd want each to be used for. So this current query will just use the values.

EDIT:

To make things simpler to start with so you can test, use this code instead, it will insert the lines one by one and make it more easy to try out first. But note that running X queries is slower than running just one (but not too much, depends on the numbers).

```
foreach($output as $line) 
{
    $var = explode('\t', $line, 2);
    $arr[$var[0]] = $var[1];
    $sql = mysql_query('INSERT INTO tbl_order_details(orderdet_id) VALUES ("'.$var[1].'")');
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Thank you..!! Your point of view is good and I appreciate, but it doesn't give the particular answer..!!

Comment: Explain yourself in more details if you want me to be able to answer better :)